# jQuery - show / hide check box after form submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a simple show / hide checkbox working on a page, which is working fine.

**HTML**

```
<label for="un-controls">Include Bells and Whistles </label>
<input class="un-controls" id="un-controls" type="checkbox" name="un-controls" value="y" />

<div id="un-controls" class="answer">
    <label for="spoon">Spoon: <input type="checkbox" name="spoon" id="spoon" value="y"></label>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".answer").hide();
$(".un-controls").click(function() {
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(".answer").show();
  } else {
    $(".answer").hide();
  }
});
```

This is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqpv1fze/

The problem I have is that once the form is submitted, I want the "Bells and Whistles" checkbox to pick up the value from when the user submits the form.

It's not a problem to add the logic into my script so that the box displays as checked after the form is submitted and I display the form again. My problem is working out how to edit the jQuery code so that it also has some logic in it to check if the "un-controls" check box is ticked (though I realise I can use if(document.getElementById('un-controls').checked), and if it is, to show the div with a class of answer, and then for the user to be able to remove the Bells and Whistles tick, even after the form has been submitted, and for the extra "Spoon" option to be hidden again, without having to resubmit the form.

I tried this:

```
if(document.getElementById('un-controls').checked) {
    $(".answer").show();
} else {
    $(".un-controls").click(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(".answer").show();
        } else {
            $(".answer").hide();
        }
    });
}
```

However, that doesn't solve it due to my flawed logic.

Comment: Submit the form with ajax and based on the results returned perform your other actions.

Comment: You had the same id "un-controls" for the first checkbox and the second div (not second checkbox). Id should be unique to each control, and advise which checkbox you want to check whether checked. If both the checkboxes then you should have a common CSS class. I guess you want to check the second checkbox, but confirm the same?

Comment: Hi @Aruna I do want to be able to check the 2nd checkbox ("Spoon") but the thing I am stuck on is how to deal with the "Bells and Whistles" option being checked when the form is submitted, and then on the resulting page, displaying the submitted form, show the Bells check ticked, and the Spoon box already visible, but for the user to then be able to toggle the Bells checkbox, and toggle the visibility of the Spoon checkbox. Ideally without rewriting all of the existing scripting logic I have on the page which doesn't currently use Ajax to submit the form (in ref to the comment from Michael).